# Chrome HTTP2 requests do not finish for large gzipped files (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, gzip, google-chrome, http2, chunked

I recently upgraded Aapche to 2.4.26 (ondrej ppa) on Ubuntu 16.04. By default, modules `deflate` and `http2` are enabled.

On Chrome, when serving large JS files, the request simply does not finish and fails with `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` after a long time has elapsed (essentially, time specified by Apache `Timeout` setting). On Firefox, everything runs perfectly.

**What I have tried**

I observed during troubleshooting:

- Small JS files work fine. The large JS file I had was 259.43KB (75.78KB gzipped)
- If I disable HTTP2 in Apache: `Protocols http/1.1`, Chrome works.
- If I manually disable gzip module: `a2dismod deflate`, Chrome works.

Of course, neither option is ideal for performance.

As a shot in the dark, I tried to turn off `KeepAlive` as suggested by the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847083/chrome-just-doesnt-finish-loading-js-files. It doesn't solve the problem.

I copied the HTTP headers of the problematic JS file From Chrome Developer Tools:

**HTTP Request Headers**

```
:authority: example.com
:method:GET
:path:/js/main.js
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
cache-control:no-cache
pragma:no-cache
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

**HTTP Response Headers**

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:max-age=7200
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/javascript; charset=utf-8
date:Mon, 03 Jul 2017 07:23:27 GMT
last-modified:Thu, 01 Jun 2017 14:49:09 GMT
server:Apache
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options:nosniff
```

I did some reading and it **could** have something to do with chunked gzip responses lacking `Content-Length` response header. It may also be due to lack of `Transfer-Encoding` response header. But I'm not sure what is the correct thing to do, or how to make Apache output those headers.

**Questions**

what seems to be the problem? How can I enable HTTP2 with gzip on my Apache web server?

If it is caused by wrong/missing headers for chunked gzipped HTTP2 responses, can anyone elucidate which headers are required? i.e. what is the correct way to serve chunked gzip HTTP2 responses?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Apache, I am currently working on. See https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/143